# (genralized) rewriting of an equivalent term under constructor?

Tags: coq, rewriting

I have an inductive type `Env` that is a snoclist with multiple cons constructors

```
Inductive Env : Set :=
 | Env_Empty : Env
 | Env_ConsA (env : Env) (a : A)
 | Env_ConsB (env : Env) (b : B)
 ...
```

The types `A` and `B` do not matter, so I have not given them. I have defined an equivalence relation `EqEnv` on these environments, and have used the documentation for [generalized rewriting](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/generalized-rewriting.html#rewriting-under-binders) to declare it as a reflexive, symmetric, and transitive (equivalence) relation:

```
Inductive EnvEq : Env -> Env -> Prop := ...
Notation "A =~ B" := (EnvEq A B) (at level 70) : type_scope.

Add Relation Env EnvEq
  reflexivity  proved by eq_env_refl
  symmetry     proved by eq_env_sym
  transitivity proved by eq_env_trans
    as eq_env_rel.
```

Note the notation `=~`. Now, this allows for rewriting some x into y given that `x =~ y`, *but only when they do not appear under a constructor/function application/(binder?)*. I figured out the case for environment concatenation `+++` on my own:

```
Fixpoint env_concat (env1 : Env) (env2 : Env) : Env := ...
Notation "A +++ B" := (env_concat A B) (at level 60).

Theorem env_concat_compat :
    forall x x' : Env, EnvEq x x' ->
    forall y y' : Env, EnvEq y y' ->
           EnvEq (x +++ y) (x' +++ y').

Add Morphism env_concat
  with signature EnvEq ==> EnvEq ==> EnvEq as eq_env_conc.
Proof.
  exact env_concat_compat.
Qed.
```

(It must be said I don't fully understand the `==>` in the signature. I know it combines `++>` and `-->` but I'm confused about what these do as well).

Now, where I am stuck is on operations that do not *return* an `Env`, but are parametarized on `Env`, i.e. constructors. The docs have a section "Rewriting under binders", is a constructor a binder in this case? When I hear binder I think lambda abstraction, but I *think* here they mean constructors, or at least that constructors are a type of binder.

```
Inductive WfEnv : Env -> Prop := ...
```

I want, with some hypothesis `H : x =~ y`, to be able to rewrite `WfEnv x` to `WfEnv y` by calling `rewrite H` or if needed `rewrite_setoid H`. I could give a lemma `x =~ y -> WfEnv x <-> WfEnv y` but I'm looking for rewriting support.

For the next step, I'm looking to rewrite constructors that are parameterized over not just `Env`, but also other types. These types can just be required to be equal by normal (Leibniz) equality.

```
Inductive Foo : Env -> A -> Prop := ...
```

Here I'm looking to, given some `hypothesis H1 : x =~ y` and `H2 : a = b`, rewrite `Foo x a` to `Foo y b`. Again, I can write a lemma `x =~y -> a = b -> Foo x a <-> Foo y b`, but I am looking for rewriting support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare `WfEnv` to be a morphism for the relation `EnvEq` as follows:

```
Add Parametric Morphism : WfEnv
    with signature EnvEq ==> iff as yourmorphism1.
Proof.
  (* apply here your lemma [x =~ y -> WfEnv x <-> WfEnv y] *)
Qed.
```

This declaration allows to rewrite equivalent `Env`s under `WfEnv`. Idem with extra parameters:

```
Add Parametric Morphism : Foo
    with signature EnvEq ==> (@eq A) ==> iff as yourmorphism2.
Proof.
  (* x =~y -> a = b -> Foo x a <-> Foo y b *)
Qed.
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this helps me out! Small correction: in the second example I you meant to write `(@eq A)`, right?

Comment: Yes indeed! (I didn't try to run the answer)